# Does the order of multiplication variables of different data type cause different results?

Tags: c, integer-promotion

Lets say I have 3 variables: a `long`, an `int` and a `short`.

```
long  l; 
int   i;
short s;
long  lsum;
```

If this is a pure math, since multiplication has a commutative property, the order of these variables doesn't matter.

```
 l * i * s = i * s * l = s * i * l.
```

Let `lsum` be the container of the  multiplication of these 3 variables.

In C,  would there be a case where a particular order of these variables cause different result?

If there is a case where the order does matter, not necessarily from this example, what would that be?

Comment: (`s*i`) is converted to int, then `(s*i) * l` to long. `(l*i)` is converted to long, then `(l*i)* s` to long also. If ever `s*i` overflows int_max, then the order can make a difference.

Comment: @aka.nice - From your comments, it looks like the type promotion happens sequentially and there can be a overflow if going from small to big.  If that is the case, starting with biggest type in the beginning would be the right thing to do.

Comment: In this case the biggest type is the same type as the product. If it is not you must cast it. (Although operands smaller than `int` will be extended to `int` internally.)

Comment: @Nguaial: There will be no overflow, but undefined behaviour. And what do you mean with  "big"? There is no guarantee `int` is smaller than `long`.

Comment: @Olaf - What i  meant by `big` is that the date type has  a higher max value: e.g. Max of long is higher than max of int.  The examples provided below are cases of UB?

Comment: @aka.nice "(s*i) is converted to int" lacks clarity.  `s` is first converted to `int`.  Then the multiplication happens.

Comment: @Nguaial  [Max of long is higher than max of int.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44055758/does-the-order-of-multiplication-variables-of-different-data-type-cause-differen#comment75137371_44055758) Not quite: `LONG_MAX >= INT_MAX`.  That is `>=` not `>`.

Comment: @: Don't rely on false assumptions! There is no guarantee any of `int`, `short` `long` has a wider range than any of the others.

Comment: @chux yes you are right, all these details explain why I did write a comment, not a whole/correct answer ;) And the most troubling issue is that an unsigned short will generally be converted to a *signed* int if it fits, which is somehow surprising for whom did not study type promotion carefully enough

Comment: @aka.nice The issue is even more _fun_ with floating point as  C allows intermediate calculations to occur at various types per `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The order does matter due to integer promotions.

When applying an arithmetic operator, each of its operands is first promoted to `int` if its rank is less than `int` (such as `char` or `short`).  If one of those operands then has a higher rank still (such as `long`), then the smaller is promoted.

From section 6.3.1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *2* The following may be used in an expression wherever an int or unsigned int may be used:
>
> - An object or expression with an integer type (other than int or unsigned int) whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to
>   the rank of int and unsigned int.
> - A bit-field of type _Bool, int, signed int, or unsigned int.
>
> If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted
> by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an int;
> otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the
> integer promotions. All other types are unchanged by the integer
> promotions.

From section 6.3.1.8:

> If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is
> needed.
>
> Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have
> unsigned integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer
> conversion rank is converted to the type of the operand with greater
> rank.
>
> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank
> greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then
> the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the
> operand with unsigned integer type.
>
> Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can
> represent all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned
> integer type, then the operand with unsigned integer type is converted
> to the type of the operand with signed integer type.
>
> Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type
> corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type.

As an example (assuming `sizeof(int)` is 4 and `sizeof(long)` is 8):

```
int i;
short s;
long l, result;

i = 0x10000000;
s = 0x10;
l = 0x10000000;

result = s * i * l;
printf("s * i * l=%lx\n", result);
result = l * i * s;
printf("l * i * s=%lx\n", result);
```

Output:

```
s * i * l=0
l * i * s=1000000000000000
```

In this example, `s * i` is evaluated first.  The value of `s` is promoted to `int`, then the two `int` values are multiplied.  At this point an overflow occurs invoking undefined behavior.  The result is then promoted to `long` and multiplied by `l`, with the result being of type `long`.

In the latter case, `l * i` is evaluated first.  The value of `i` is promoted to `long`, then the two `long` values are multiplied and an overflow does *not* occur.  The result is then multiplied by `s`, which is first promoted to `long`.  Again, the result does not overflow.

In a situation like this, I'd recommend casting the leftmost operand to `long` so that all other operands are promoted to that type.  If you have parenthesized subexpressions you may need to apply a cast there as well, depending on the result you want.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, see "Type conversion" and "Type promotion" on http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/DE18T05o/

```
unsigned a = INT_MAX;
unsigned b = INT_MAX;
unsigned long c = 255;

unsigned long r1 = a * b * c;
unsigned long r2 = c * a * b;
```

r1=255
r2=13835056960065503487

r1 reflects that (a*b) is done first with types as least as long as an int, and the result is of the longest operand type, which is unsigned, so the result is unsigned and that overflows.

Comment: Obviously `r2` is the right answer.  So is it safe to say to always start with biggest type as the first variable in the order of multiplication?

Comment: @Nguaial the safe way is to cast the first operand to the target type.

Comment: For safety, do what Weather Vane mentioned.  If the biggest type is first, you may still never expand to a wide enough type to hold your answer.  e.g. `unsigned long r0 = a * b` will have value '1' because of overflow.  But if you `unsigned long r0 = (unsigned long)a * b`, you'll get the expansion and expected answer.